# Why did I get a Request Timeout in my Jenkins Pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, httprequest

i created a Pipeline which is doing a "smoke test" after the deployment via http request against the info endpoint of my 2 deployed apps.
I did this with a 3 times retry, because on of the requests ran into a timeout.
but these 3 retries are still not enough - so the pipeline kind of "crashes".

Here is my code:

```
void smoketests() {
  retry(3) {
    try {
      SMOKE_TEST_PORTS.each {
        port ->
          String url = isReleaseBranch() ?
            "https://<url>:${port}/actuator/info" :
            "http://<url>:${port}/actuator/info"
          def responseJson = readJSON(text:
            httpRequest(consoleLogResponseBody: true, timeout: 60, httpMode: 'GET', ignoreSslErrors: true, url: url)
          .content)
        if (!responseJson.build.version.equals(POM.getVersion())) {
          throw new Exception("Not expected version number (${responseJson.build.version})")
        }
    }
  } catch (err) {
    println err
    sleep(time: 20, unit: 'SECONDS')
    throwError('can\'t reach health endpoint(s) or not expected version number')
  }
}
if (isReleaseBranch()) {
  sendMattermostMsg("released ${PROJECT} with version ${POM.getVersion()} on UAT")
}
```

}

So i added now a timeout of 60 seconds, but this still crashes sometimes. But the endpoints are reachable via browser. is there a mistake of mine in the pipeline code?

Here are the logs:

```
HttpMethod: GET
URL: https://<url>:11761/actuator/info
Sending request to url: https://<url>:11761/actuator/info
Treating class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException(Connect to 
<url>:11761 [<url>] failed: Connection refused (Connection refused)) as 408 Request Timeout
Response: 
class org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException(Connect to <url>:11761 [<url>] failed: Connection 
refused (Connection refused)) as 408 Request Timeout
[Pipeline] echo
java.lang.IllegalStateException: hudson.AbortException: Fail: the returned code 408 is not in the accepted range: [[100‥399]]
[Pipeline] sleep
Sleeping for 20 sec
... etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you behind a corporate proxy?  I just spent ages trying to find the correct syntax for the proxy authentication.

If so, something like this could work for you:

```
def response = httpRequest url: "http://postman-echo.com/get?test=123", httpProxy: "http://proxy.yourcompany.com:8080", customHeaders: [[name: 'Proxy-Authorization', value: 'Basic xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', maskValue: true]]
```

To get the value of "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", type the proxy credentials into a browser in this format:   javascript:btoa("username:password")